# Why is the Visual Studio 2013 debugger closing without error when I try to expand Model properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I have a small ASP.NET MVC5 project using Entity Framework Code First. I have placed a breakpoint in my controller so that I can examine the contents of my variables to ensure that they all contain what they should contain. One such variable is a complex model object which I query from the context and when I try to expand that object to view its properties, the debugger simply closes with no obvious error message. The only explanation that I get is in the Output which reads:

> ```
> The program '[10820] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
> The program '[10820] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -2147023895 (0x800703e9).
> The program '[12128] iexplore.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
> ```

I looked up exit code -2147023895 (0x800703e9) and only got that it is a stack overflow issue which really doesn't help to figure out what is causing it.

The most unusual thing is that if I let the application run, it loads the page with no problem and doesn't seem to throw any errors at all. What's going on here?

Here's my relevant code:

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //This is the line that crashed the debugger if I try to expand quarter
    //after it is filled. There will only ever by one item marked isCurrent.
    Quarter quarter = db.Quarter.First(x => x.isCurrent == true);

    ...
}
```

Model

```
public class Quarter
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public Enums.QuarterEnum Quarter {get; set;}
    public string Year {get; set;}
    public bool isCurrent {get; set;}
    [NotMapped]
    public string QuarterAndYear {get{ return QuarterAndYear; }}
}
```

View

```
...
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Quarter.Quarter)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Quarter.Quarter)
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I searched around for a solution to this problem but could not find anything that really helped me so I opted to post this here with an explanation of why this occurred and the super easy change that fixed it.

The problem was in the model with the line:

```
public string QuarterAndYear {get{ return QuarterAndYear; }}
```

A careless mistake on my part by telling it to return itself which caused me a huge headache in trying to figure out why it was crashing with no error message. It should have been:

```
public string QuarterAndYear {get{ return Quarter.toString() + " Quarter of " + Year;}}
```

Because I was not actually referencing the QuarterAndYear in the view, no errors were thrown when I loaded the page and it seemed to run perfectly. However, when I tried to view the properties of the Quarter object while debugging, it was trying to resolve QuarterAndYear (which was returning itself) and was crashing the debugger.